# How to use varray in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, varray

Below code block is throwing error..

```
DECLARE
  TYPE dbadaptor IS VARRAY (9) OF VARCHAR2(20);
  min_date DATE;
  max_date DATE;
  db       dbadaptor := dbadaptor('wsf_ds_11765_c', 'wsf_ds_11750_c',
                                  'wsf_ds_11756_c', 'wsf_ds_11759_c',
                                  'wsf_ds_11706_c', 'wsf_ds_11709_c', 
                                  'wsf_ds_11751_c', 'wsf_ds_11708_c',
                                  'wsf_ds_11762_c');
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..9 LOOP
    SELECT
      from_sf_date(max(start_time)),
      from_sf_date(min(start_time))
    INTO max_date, min_date
    FROM db(i);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I am getting an error at line 8 ” PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended ” and this is because of db(i)….
Can you please help me out

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of problems with your code:

1. You can't access datatypes defined in PL/SQL in a SQL statement.
2. In order to access an array in the from clause, you need to use the `table` function.
3. You're trying to select `start_time` from your array, but you have no such column defined. The only column you have is a string with an undefined name (which would be referenced as `column_value`).

Below is an example that demonstrate the techniques referenced in problems 1 and 2 (I lack enough information to provide a solution for problem 3).

```
CREATE TYPE dbadaptor AS VARRAY(9) OF VARCHAR2(20);

DECLARE
   min_date DATE;
   max_date DATE;
   db       dbadaptor
               := dbadaptor('wsf_ds_11765_c',
                            'wsf_ds_11750_c',
                            'wsf_ds_11756_c',
                            'wsf_ds_11759_c',
                            'wsf_ds_11706_c',
                            'wsf_ds_11709_c',
                            'wsf_ds_11751_c',
                            'wsf_ds_11708_c',
                            'wsf_ds_11762_c');
BEGIN    
   FOR db_value IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE AS CV FROM TABLE(db)) LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(db_value.CV);
   END LOOP;    
END;
/
```

However, this is an inefficient way to loop through an array. If that's all you're doing, you'd be better off just using a loop:

```
DECLARE
   type dbadaptor is VARRAY(9) OF VARCHAR2(20);
   min_date DATE;
   max_date DATE;
   db       dbadaptor
               := dbadaptor('wsf_ds_11765_c',
                            'wsf_ds_11750_c',
                            'wsf_ds_11756_c',
                            'wsf_ds_11759_c',
                            'wsf_ds_11706_c',
                            'wsf_ds_11709_c',
                            'wsf_ds_11751_c',
                            'wsf_ds_11708_c',
                            'wsf_ds_11762_c');
   i number;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..9 LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(db(i));
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```